# Unable to ping scan my machine (but I can ping)

Tags: networking, security, nmap

I need to perform an nmap scan on all of the (responding) IPs in an array of VLANs.

The command is nested in a PowerShell for loop and looks something like this:

```
nmap.exe -Pn -T4 -A -oG [FILE].txt -oX [FILE].xml "$($subnet).0/24"
```

We had to add the `-Pn` flag as the command wasn't picking up all of the hosts in each VLAN with a ping scan.

The issue is that we believe the command is taking too long and so we would like to only scan the hosts that respond to the ping scan.

I found one machine that responds to a simple `ping [MACHINE]` however running `nmap -sn [MACHINE]` results in:

> “Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn”

I'm not sure why I am able to ping the machine but nmap isn't? Running nmap in an Administrator PowerShell console does not resolve the issue.

I ran this on the problem machine in order to allow ICMP traffic but this did not work either:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

This is driving me crazy. Is anyone able to help me with this?